# Go back to initial view controller from a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm building an app use bluetooth for communication, and I have a class called `EAController`(NSObject) to handle the accessory delegate.

So if the phone lost bluetooth communication, an accessory delegate method is called in EAController where I can show an alert. What I want to do is to when lost communication, show an alert and go back to the initial view controller.

I know I can add a notification, and have all the view controllers listen to that, and the current view controller can take care of the "Go Back to First View Controller" action.

But my app has so many view controllers, so is there any way I can go back to the initial view controller through the `EAController` class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the notification in your app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation was a little vague, some code might help me understand the problem better but it sounds like UINavigationController `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` might be what you are looking for.

If EAController is a UIViewController, and has been added a navigation controller, it should have a reference to the nav controller to call the method.

Comment: Hi, Kevin, EAController is only a NSObject to handle bluetooth communication. So I guess I can't call popToRootViewControllerAnimated from there. And uinavigationcontroller is embedded right after my initial view controller.

Comment: There are a couple of ways you can address this. Passing a reference of your `UINavigationController` to `EAController` is a possibility, or having `EAController` call back to your App Delegate, which probably has a reference to the `UINavigationController` you are using.

Comment: How should I have EAController call back to app delegate?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `UINavigationController` you could us the 
`-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with storyboards and segues you should look into **unwind** segues. There are several good tutorials on the net., eg.

http://cocoatouch.blogspot.nl/2013/02/unwinding-segues-in-storyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are using UInavigationController:
for(UIViewController* vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers)                                                                if([vc isKindOfClass:FirstViewController] 
     {
       [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc anmated:YES];
       break;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` will do what you want. If you are in a part of the code where you do not have direct access to the `UINavigationController` you can push an event and configure your navigation controller to receive it. Like so:

Where you have your navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

// subscribe to the notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"goBack!" 
                                                  object:nil 
                                                   queue:nil 
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification) {

    // pop!
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}];
```

Now, somewhere else in the code... do this when you want to go back:

```
// post the notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:
    [[NSNotification alloc] initWithName:@"goBack!" 
                                  object:nil 
                                userInfo:nil]];
```